# How to Scrape a list in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I apologise in advance if my question is not written in a proper way. I've been trying to scrape https://www.bristol.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/search/search_results?sort=score&sort=UndergraduateCourse-programname&dir=desc&dir=asc&query=&filter%3AUndergraduateCourse-year=2021&page=1

I want only the text of all the course names. The code i've written only gives me the text of the first course even when i've used find-all. I think maybe this is because the courses are in a list.
Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get("https://www.bristol.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/search/search_results?sort=score&sort=UndergraduateCourse-programname&dir=desc&dir=asc&query=&filter%3AUndergraduateCourse-year=2021&page=1").text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for div in soup.find_all('div', class_='course-results course-results-ug'):
    course = div.a.text
    print(course)
```

The output comes:

```
            Accounting and Finance
        , 
            BSc
```

Please help. I've begun only recently so dont know any advanced coding

Comment: Learning [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is an extremely valuable skill for a programmer.
Please go through the linked page and apply the techniques described there to your problem to narrow down the cause of the error. Printing what you get from `soup.find_all(...)` should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selector `.course-results-list a` to get all links under the course list:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


source = requests.get("https://www.bristol.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/search/search_results?sort=score&sort=UndergraduateCourse-programname&dir=desc&dir=asc&query=&filter%3AUndergraduateCourse-year=2021&page=1").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('.course-results-list a'):
    course = ', '.join(map(str.strip, a.text.split(',')))
    print(course)
```

Prints:

```
Accounting and Finance, BSc
Accounting and Finance with Professional Placement, BSc
Accounting and Finance with Study Abroad, BSc
Accounting and Management, BSc
Accounting and Management with Professional Placement, BSc
Accounting and Management with Study Abroad, BSc
Aerospace Engineering, BEng
Aerospace Engineering, MEng
Aerospace Engineering with Study Abroad, MEng
Aerospace Engineering with Study Abroad in a Modern Language, MEng
```

Comment: Wow that works. Well i don't understand what a css selecter is and some of the other code too. Guess i'll youtube it. Could you tell why my code wasn't working?

Comment: @AnmolWadera If you inspect the HTML code you will see the class `course-results course-results-ug` is found only once in the page. It's the topmost element, that encompasses the result list. So you will see only one result.